# Focus Mode with App-based Schedule not working properly

Tags: macos, notifications, ventura, do-not-disturb, focus

I'm setting up a new MacBook Pro with macOS Ventura. I'm excited about the new Focus Modes, and created a custom mode called Video Conferencing.

My goal is for the Focus Mode to turn on when I'm running Zoom or Skype, and to turn off when I quit those applications.

Looking at the UI, it seems clear that's how it's supposed to work:

```
Video Conferencing will turn on when zoom.us is opened and turn off when it's closed.
```

[image]

While it is turning on when I open Zoom, and off when I close Zoom, it's also toggling every time I put focus on a different app, or come back to Zoom.

How do I keep the Focus Mode enabled while the app is running, and automatically disabled when the app closes?